# InvalidOperationException when sending get request in browser tab despite working in ajax

Tags: angularjs, ajax, asp.net-web-api2, umbraco, umbraco7

I have an ajax request done with angular, its very basic, here is the code:

```
$http.get(url,data).success(function(data){
    //Do Stuff with data
});
```

This works fine and the data is all good.
But when i inspect the request on the network tab in Chrome, and i right click on the request and click Open in new tab I get the following error:

```
<ExceptionMessage>
    The 'ObjectContent`1' type failed to serialize the response body for content type 'application/xml; charset=utf-8'.
</ExceptionMessage>
<ExceptionType>System.InvalidOperationException</ExceptionType>
```

Here is the api controller code:

```
[AcceptVerbs("GET")]
public object SearchRetailers(long userId, string term)
{
    List<Tuple<int,string>> res = userService.SearchRetailers(userId, term);
    return res.Take(20).Select(x => new
    {
        label = x.Item2 + " - " + x.Item1,
        value = x.Item1
    });
}
```

The code works fine and does not throw any exceptions.
i think this might have something to do with the request headers, i just want it to work when opened in the browser regularly.

Its important to note I am using Umbraco so the apicontroller inherits UmbracoApiController class.

Also, i don't see any apiwebconfig file anywhere so i cant implement other solutions i found, and my global asax also looks significantly different than in other questions i encountered, here is how it looks:

```
<%@ Application Inherits="Umbraco.Web.UmbracoApplication" Language="C#" %>
<script RunAt="server">
    protected void Application_PostAuthorizeRequest()
    {
        if (IsWebApiRequest())
        {
            HttpContext.Current.SetSessionStateBehavior(SessionStateBehavior.Required);
        }
    }

    private bool IsWebApiRequest()
    {
        return HttpContext.Current.Request.AppRelativeCurrentExecutionFilePath.Contains("/api/");
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Have you checked the Umbraco logs? Maybe you can get more info there.

Comment: Nope... nothing helpful there, a very strange occurrence indeed.